# jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'mobile' of undefined in react app

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, reactjs

I am using `react 0.14.8` and I have already imported `jquery 2.2.3` like below.

```
var jQuery = $ = require('jquery');
```

When I load my page, I get the error

> jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property
>   'mobile' of undefined in react app

Comment: Load it before jquery mobile.

Comment: The reason is probably that the regular JQuery is not accessible. Check if Jquery is accessible, if you are including file using CDN, try to include it as a file - worked for me and I've realized that I had a typo in CDN URL

Answer (score 1):

Being a "let's use the latest lib" guy, I faced the same problem as you are. Took a few silly clicks and scans to finally actually read their [jquerymobile webpage](http://blog.jquerymobile.com/2014/10/31/jquery-mobile-1-4-5-released/):

**Copy-and-Paste Snippet for CDN-hosted files:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Note: 1.11.1 worked, whereas as I typed now latest 1.12.4 - not

--- EDIT ---

I actually use [Google CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery)